# UITextField secureEntry misplaces cursor

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I'm having issues with toggling the `secureEntry` property on `UITextField`. When the property is toggled, the characters are resized, but the cursor stays in the wrong place:

[image: insecure entry]
[image: secure entry]

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITextField secureTextEntry - works going from YES to NO, but changing back to YES has no effect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6710019/uitextfield-securetextentry-works-going-from-yes-to-no-but-changing-back-to-y)

Comment: @Andrei totally did the trick. you're the man

Answer (score 4):

Here is my workaround:

```
textField.secureTextEntry = YES;

UITextRange *textRange = textField.selectedTextRange;
textField.selectedTextRange = nil;
textField.selectedTextRange = textRange;
```

Disable and then Enable the UITextField also help, but it will suddenly change my soft keyboard from one to another

Answer (score 4):

After setting textField `secureEntry` property `NO`, you need to call `becomeFirstResponder` method its works for me...

Try this

```
 textField.secureTextEntry = NO;
 if (textField.isFirstResponder){
    [textField becomeFirstResponder];
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Both are working for Swift 4

```
self.isSecureTextEntry = false

if textField.isFirstResponder {
    textField.becomeFirstResponder()
    textField.layoutIfNeeded() 
}
```

I had to add `textField.layoutIfNeeded()` that it's working for Swift or use

```
    let textRange = self.selectedTextRange
    self.selectedTextRange = nil;
    self.selectedTextRange = textRange
```

Answer (score 1):

For Swift 4

```
@objc func tapOnLeftIcon(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let textRange = textField.selectedTextRange

        textField.isSecureTextEntry = !textField.isSecureTextEntry
        textField.selectedTextRange = nil
        textField.selectedTextRange = textRange
    }
```