# VoiceOver UIAccessibilityAnnouncementNotification tone of voice

Tags: objective-c, ios, accessibility

Using `UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityAnnouncementNotification, string);` to announce things with VoiceOver. This works great for summaries etc.

The problem is in announcing entered/deleted text, VoiceOver uses a deeper tone when echoing the text you enter, and deeper still when you delete text. The documentation mentions no way to control the tone of Voice, is there some unicode character you can put in the string or any argument you can pass to do this?

Comment: I'd suggest you dont mess with how voiceover works. sighted people may have different requirements. But I think the tones are different for a reason, which most VO users are used to. changing it to anything else may throw them off balance

Comment: The intent of changing the tone is to make it match the expected tone. If you use VoiceOver you will notice that entered text is always announced with a deeper voice. And I would like my custom keyboard to match the behavior of the standard keyboard.

Comment: True. In that case, it makes sense. Are you using a custom text field/view and setting the inputView as your customkeyboard?

Comment: Yes, precisely. The keyboard is custom view with regular UIButtons for special symbols.