# Is there any way to customize the appearance and size of a keyboard on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, iphone-softkeyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Customizing the iPhone keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014705/customizing-the-iphone-keyboard)

Is there any way to customize the appearance and size of a keyboard on the iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can create your own.  You give up some functionality, but then you do gain some advantages, depending on what you are doing.  For example, if you expect only certain words to be typed in, then you can be smart and as the user types, disable keys that would produce non-sensical words.  For example, if you know that the user, after typing in an E, can only be wanting to type Edward, Elvis or Elizabeth, then you can disable all keys but D, L, and backspace, since those are the only keys the user could possibly want.  Also, you can do fancy things like display the letters on your keyboard in lowercase or upper case depending on whether the shift key was pressed.  You could even have a caps lock key...

So while there isn't a way to modify the existing keyboard, there is the possibility to replicate it yourself.