# New key on the keyboard

Tags: iphone, ios4, keyboard

I work on a iPhone project with iOS 4 and Xcode 4.

In a view I have several UITextField, that the user fills with numbers. So only the `Numbers` keyword is used.

When the user fills in a text field and click <kbd>Go</kbd>, some processing is started (modification of the text of several textFields).

Now I would like to consider also a second option: user open the keyboard but then decides to close it without any process (i.e. <kbd>cancel</kbd> the process).

So I need a keyboard with a <kbd>cancel</kbd> key as shown on this the picture:

[image]

Finally my question: how can I create a keyboard with a <kbd>cancel</kbd> key as above?

Edit: picture of my view

[image]

Comment: Many duplicates, e.g. [Customizing the iPhone keyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014705/customizing-the-iphone-keyboard)

Comment: Just a sidenote, a suggestion for your UI: the symbol `÷` does not indicate a range but a division. You should user "0 ~ 255" instead of  "0 ÷ 255".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyboard cannot be modified.  You should add a cancel button, or some other way of triggering a cancel, in your UI.

Comment: I could perhaps use the key "space" as cancel. "Space" is currently captured by shouldChangeCharactersInRange

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it.  A button should do what it says.  Again, you should add a cancel button, or another way trigger a cancel, in your UI in some way.

Comment: unfortunately there is very little space. see picture above